# Is there actually a minimum API level for AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android

I have read that AppCompatActivity can be used from API levels 15 and on. I work with API level 17 and Eclipse (Neon) and I can't make it work. I have added both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in Ref libraries and I'm of course importing android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.

More specifically:

1) style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" doesn't work. I get a "No resource found that matches ..." error.

2) If I don't use this (so that Eclipse can complile the project), the app crashes immediately (by simply extending the main activity to 'AppCompatActivity' (instead to just 'Activity').

So, is there a minimum API Level or some special setting needed for using AppCompatActivity that I could not find anywhere?

(Please do not reference me to similar issues posted already in stackoverflow.com. I have read them almost all, with their replies. They suggest to import the 'appcompt' jars, etc., which I did already from day one. And they all suggest to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (or NoActionBar, etc.) as standard, which for me doesn't work.)

Comment: A jar can only hold java classes. The additional xml resources are missing. Therefore import the Android Appcompat lib as android library. You will find a lot of answers how to do this. Additionally it might be more easier to use Android Studio.

Comment: There are various version of Support library available ( v4, v7, v13 ). Please refer url https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html to understand various versions and their compatibility. e.g. if you use V24 which supports Android Version9.0. Support for 8 and lower is decprecated using v24.

Comment: here is link to setup to your project https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Thank you. However, I asked a solution using *Eclipse*.